# Drupal 7 custom module load css for specific theme template

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-theming

I have a custom module that i've created and I have set the theme template like this:

```
/**
 * Implemtnation of hook_theme()
 */
function custom_slider_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
    return array(
        'custom_slider' => array(
            'variables' => array('nodes' => NULL),
            'template' => 'custom_slider',
        ),
    );
}
```

This is all working fine.

What I can't find is how to load a css file for that template so when `custom_slider.tpl.php` is loaded the relevent css file is loaded. I don't need that css loaded on every page. I would rather call `drupal_add_css()` only when it's needed.

Any help with this is very much appreciated.

C

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add it in a preprocess function, e.g.

```
function custom_slider_preprocess_custom_slider(&$vars) {
  drupal_add_css(drupal_get_path('module', 'custom_slider') . '/file.css');
}
```

Comment: Thnaks @Clive - But what if I want the module to be self seficient and loads it's own resources? I know how to add it to the .info file of the module but I only want it to load when the templete used in that module is being used.

Comment: Not sure I understand - the above method is exactly how to do that unless I've missed something?

Comment: You can implement a preprocess function for a theme in the same module that defines that theme - could that be the confusion?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. Does this function add the css to every page or just the page that uses the template `custom_slider.tpl.php` which is only called when the url is `/mycustomslider`

Comment: The CSS will only be added when `theme('custom_slider')` is called, so it won't be added to any page that doesn't call it